# How often to use REM in CSS

Tags: css

I'm not sure if this is really the right place for this question, so if someone knows of a more appropriate StackExchange site, please share and I will be happy to move the question.

I'm currently trying to make it a habit to use relative measurements for CSS instead of `px` to accommodate the ever-increasing number of users who have ultra-high resolution monitors i.e. 4K.

In doing so, I got to thinking - should `rem` be used for everything that would have used `px`?

I'm currently finding that I'm using `rem` for `border-radius`, `margin`, `padding`, and `font-size`. After searching the interwebs for a bit, I couldn't really come up with any sort of guide for what is appropriate to use rem on, so I figured I would ask here - Are there any cases where you wouldn't want to use `rem` or `em` as the measurement for a property, but instead use `px`?  Or is it pretty much just commonplace to use `rem` for everything?

Comment: For border widths, I'd avoid rems. Some browsers round differently to pixels than others, so you'd create browser incompatibilities. With pixels, you know what you'll get! For things related to text containers like p, div, h1 etc, I'd use em rather than rem. Other than that, this is asking for opinions and therefore off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rem is relative to the font size defined in the root node while em is relative to the font size of the current node.

I generally use rem for everything except if the value depends on the font size of the current element.
E.g. Given two versions of a H2 title: h2 with 40px and h2.large with 45px, then the bottom margin is relative to the size of the h2 element if you used em here.

I would use Pixels for small values such as border-width. The rendering is usually better.

Comment: Makes sense to me, thanks for the clarifications!